# Ionic 4 - cordova-admob-pro won't show ads after uploaded

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-admob

Trying to show banner Ads in my app

#### The Behavior

- Test ads show correctly in emulators
- Real ads show correctly in the Ionic DevApp
- Real ads show correctly when side-loading the signed app apk, prior to upload to Google Play
- Ads FAIL in both Internal Testing and Full Production Release (Google Play)

#### My Configuration

- cordova-plugin-admobpro: 2.35.3
- Ionic: 4.5.0
- Cordova: 8.1.2
- Android: 7.1.4

#### In my home.ts file...

```
      constructor(...,...,...,){
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.loadBanner();
        });
      }

   loadBanner(){
    let adId = 'ca-app-pub-634383******/*****';
    this.admob.createBanner({adId: adId})
    .then(() => { this.admob.showBanner(8); });
    }
```

I get no errors or warnings of any kind. Does anyone have ideas what's going on? My ads have been active in Admob for 3 or 4 weeks, so it's not a timing thing.

What's happening during the upload process that causes the admob plugin to fail?  Everything else in the app works as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Ok...   A day later the ads started showing up.

Comment: I guess I don't know why they would show up fine (and instantly) in a signed 'release' apk, but need more time to start showing from a published version.  But all-right, looks like it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... A day later the ads started showing up.